# Getting numbers from string as a pattern and storing it in an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have a string of 5 numbers, and I need to separate them and store them in an array. I've been trying to come up with a function to do this for hours, unsuccessfully, so I'm wondering if anyone have any ideas of accomplishing this, or if there is a build-in method to do this?

```
$string = "1 2 3 4 5"
```

**Required Outcomes**

```
$array[0] = "1 2 3 4 5" (5)

$array[1] = "1 2 3 4" (4) 
$array[2] = "2 3 4 5" (4)

$array[3] = "1 2 3" (3)
$array[4] = "2 3 4" (3)
$array[5] = "3 4 5" (3)

$array[6] = "1 2" (2)
$array[7] = "2 3" (2) 
$array[8] = "3 4" (2)
$array[9] = "4 5" (2)

$array[10] = "1" (1)
$array[11] = "2" (1)
$array[12] = "3" (1)
$array[13] = "4" (1)
$array[14] = "5" (1)
```

P.S: The example string's numbers are 5 of them, but that's just an example. The working function should work with any amount of numbers. Thank you.

Edit: I do not need a function to explode this. I already know the explode function. I'm asking for a function to get me the results below Required Outcomes no matter the amount of numbers. So if numbers are "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10", the outcome would be like the patterns below require outcomes.

The focus should be on the patterns below required outcomes. Those patterns are the patterns that I want to get. I need a function get get those exact patterns.

**More Examples**

```
$string = "1 2 3 4"

$array[0] = "1 2 3 4"

$array[1] = "1 2 3"
$array[2] = "2 3 4"

$array[3] = "1 2"
$array[4] = "2 3"
$array[5] = "3 4"

$array[6] = "1"
$array[7] = "2"
$array[8] = "3"
$array[9] = "4"
```

Comment: `$result = explode(' ', $text);`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski No. It should be a function that explodes it, before storing it in that way.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Did you really think that I was asking about how to explode a string?

Comment: @jessica
Can you explain, *It should be a function that explodes it* ?

Comment: I've read your question again. If you're not asking how to explode a string, then I don't understand your question (which means it's unclear and needs more detail).

Comment: @jessica, yes. Unless you clarify, the clear answer is explode

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I do not need a function to explode this. I already know the explode function. I'm asking for a function to get me the results below Required Outcomes no matter the amount of numbers. So if numbers are "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10", the outcome would be like the patterns below require outcomes.

Comment: The answer is still clearly explode. Maybe you are confused on what explode does. It puts the values into an array, exactly as you have asked.

Comment: @Runthis Yes I know what explode does. But it doesn't solve my question at all. Using explode, I would only get an array with all 5 numbers, BUT THE NUMBERS ARE NOT LIKE THE PATTERNS BELOW. I'm confused. Are you guys just ignoring that last part or what?

Comment: May I suggest you to write the desired output in PHP object notation (as if you passed it to `var_dump`)? This would make things unambiguous.

Comment: The first line of your question is not worded this way.

Comment: Nice. Now your requirement is pretty clear :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I've edited it. Maybe this would make more sense.

Comment: @jessica
Can you post an example taking a string having "1,2,3,4" (4 numbers) ?

Comment: @Akshay Yes. Just did.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski So, any thoughts?

Comment: @jessica yup, I was writing an answer, don't be in such a hurry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function which does this:

```
function do_the_thing($string) {
    $numbers = explode(' ', $string);
    $result = array();

    for ($n = count($numbers); $n >= 1; --$n) {
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($numbers) - $n; ++$i) {
            $result[] = implode(' ', array_slice($numbers, $i, $n));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ihpUIU)

Basically:

- `$n` is the number count needed in a given pass. Goes from the number count down to 1.
- `$i` is the start index at which a new result item should start copying from the input string. Starts at 0 and increments for each result item until the items's last number is the same as the input's last number.

Comment: Okay. You're a genius of the highest level. Not sure if I could come up with something like that even if I rack my brain for hours.

Comment: Oh I'm sure you could. It just requires dividing the problem into smaller problems, until the small problems are trivial to solve. By the way I've simplified the code quite a bit (I was reinventing `array_slice` - I usually don't use PHP very much).